# Store GitHub token in a shell variable Linux Debian

Tags: linux, git, github, debian

I am a new programmer, and also still a "noob" using Debian based distributions and Linux in general. Every time I push to my GitHub repository as u know, I have to write username and password which is my GitHub token, I have the token stored in a file and I have to enter the file copy the token and use it, and it's a bit annoying, I know it's possible to store commands in variables to make shell use faster, is there some sort of way to do the same with my token? or which would be a good practice to do so?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache your username/password with this command:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=secs'
```

where ***secs*** (seconds) defaults to 900 (15 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using SSH keys which you can find more information about [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account). When authenticating using SSH keys you don't have to type in your password manually.

A few things that would change would be that you should select the SSH option instead when you're going to clone your repository.

I believe the following command can change this configuration for repos that you've already cloned using HTTPS:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<repository-name>`

[image: Menu to select SSH instead of HTTPS]